# Scan Fb QRCode to login app

Tags: android

I'm creating new application that scan Facebook QR Code to login.
The result will same as u click "Login with Facebook" in website.
But my app is use Facebook QR Code to do that. My app will scan the QR Code from your phone
then it will login to my app by Facebook account. Now i'm done the scan code but don't know how to use that code to login as Facebook account. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need integrate facebook SDK.
[facebook developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/)

Comment: i tried already, but it's not what i want. I want to scan FB QR Code to login not click to "Continue With Facebook" then type your username, password to login. My idea is my app scan the QR Code then auto login to that account. No need to type username, password.

Comment: thank you i found the issue, cannot do as i'm thinking, now FB dont support this.